# React JS Map con OnClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy intentando imprimir una **lista de productos** e incluir un **boton** para cada producto
Utilice la funcion Map y le agrego a cada elemento la propiedad OnClick() pero no me reconoce las funciones de la clase.

*Js*

```
 remove=()=>{
        this.props.removerCarrito(this.props.item);
        console.log("remove");
      }
    return (
        <div className="modal">
    <div onClick={this.props.onClose} className="overlay"></div>
          <div className="modal-content">
           {this.props.pedido.map(function(item, i){
            return <p className="itemList"key={i}>{item} - <span onClick={this.remove}className="remove">Remover</span></p>
        })}

            {
                

            } 
      );
    }
    
  }
  export default Modal;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como estas usando `function` dentro del map, `this` no va a ser referencia a la clase.

Lo mas practico es usar fat arrow functions, asi:

```
{this.props.pedido.map((item, i) => 
    <p className="itemList"key={i}>{item} - <span onClick={this.remove}className="remove">Remover</span></p>)
}
```

Además, según me parece, vas a tener que ajustar como llamas a `remove`, ya que no va a hacer lo que quieres.

Tu `onClick` deberia lucir asi:

```js
onClick={() => this.remove(item)}
```

y tu `remove` function:

```js
remove = (item) => {
  this.props.removerCarrito(item);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ahi lo probe y funciono todo Maestro!

Comment: Excelente, me alegro!